# close tcp\udp connection by process name without killing the process Autoit script

Tags: process, connection, autoit

I need help with this autoit script
It's close a tcp\udp connection of a process without killing the process
I found script in a forum but it's not working
let's say I want to close any connection established from "internet download manager"
so I put in process name

$processname = "IDMan.exe"

but it still not working !!
I guess some thing wrong in the code
Second : I want to but a WHILE loop to kill the process connection whenever it started
how can I do that

Here is the script without modifications

[Link to script](http://rghost.net/49373141)

sorry I tried to put the script source here but I failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an Admin Rights.

Add this to the top of your script

```
#RequireAdmin
```

You can use **CloseTCPConnectionByProcessName** in a while loop, just add some **sleep** to keep it stable.

Comment: Thanks Milos that works for me now but I'm currently working on my win XP OS why may I need RequireAdmin ?

Comment: XP also has UAC. Its always a good thing to add #RequireAdmin. Just in case.